# Does Windows Forms have a control for browsing drives, directories, files

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer, vb6-migration

Back in a day, Visual Studio 6 had:

- `DriveListBox`
- `DirListBox`
- `FileListBox`

Does Windows Forms have something similar built-in, or is there a way to import it from VS6 (I came across some terms like VB6 compatibility or backward compatibility or something, but I don't know how to implement it)

If it's not possible, can you point me to some more modern solution, a component that would enable user to browse his file system?

Comment: [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6?view=netframework-4.8) has [DriveListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.drivelistbox.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) so you should be covered for everything you know from VB6.

Comment: ... but they come with limitations: Only supported for 32bit applications.

Comment: Thx. How do I import it?

Comment: Reference the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility assembly.

Comment: I did, but I still cannot find those controls in the list All Windows Forms where all controls are listed I suppose. I restarted the solution. And I imported the assembly by `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6;` Maybe those controls are renamed?

Comment: What you probably don't have are the .Net classes available for this purpose. See, for example, [DriveInfo.GetDrives()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives) and [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles) or [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories), etc. -- Try something like `[Some ListBox].DataSource = DriveInfo.GetDrives()` -- A ComboBox can set its `AutoCompleteSource` to `FileSystem`. And so on.

Comment: A follow up. See, for example, the [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.isreadonly) object: among its methods: `CopyTo()`, `MoveTo()`, `Encrypt()`, `Decrypt()`, `Replace()` etc. Also, see, for example, the `IsReadonly` property: note that is a Get/Set Property. If you set the value, you actually change the attribute of the File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out about FolderBrowserDialog and the implementation:

```
    var d = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    d.ShowDialog();
```

This will do nicely.

Comment: I didn't use any additional assembly. In my question, I asked "Does Windows Forms have something similar built-in..." and "If it's not possible, can you point me to some more modern solution, a component that would enable user to browse his file system". My own answer is to this second question.